# FOSRestBundle return object error

Tags: php, validation, symfony, fosrestbundle

I use FOERestBundle and class View. And when I validate entity I have object error like this and this is:

```
[
 {
   "property_path": "main_skill",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 },
 {
   "property_path": "type",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 },
 {
   "property_path": "description",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 }
]
```

I need return object error when user not valid security token like this

```
[
 {
   "property_path": "main_skill",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 },
]
```

now I have plain text. This my end point

```
    /**
 * Update existing Bit from the submitted data.
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 * resource = true,
 * description = "Update single Bit",
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="status", "dataType"="string", "required"=false, "description"="status for bit"},
 *      {"name"="text", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="text for rejected"},
 *      {"name"="token", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="is equally md5('email'.secret_word)"}
 *  },
 * statusCodes = {
 *      200 = "Bit successful update",
 *      400 = "Secret token is not valid"
 * },
 *  section="Bit"
 * )
 * @RestView()
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string  $id
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function putBitAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $token = $this->get('request')->request->get('token');
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findOneBySecuritytoken($token);
    $bit = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Bit')->find($id);
    $view = View::create();

    if (!empty($user) && !empty($bit) && !empty($token)) {

            *some logic
            $view = $this->view($bit, 200);

            return $this->handleView($view);
        }
    } else {
        $view = $this->view('Secret token is not valid', 400);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

now I have plain text

```
Response Body [Raw]
"Secret token is not valid"
```

this is return object error validate and this is ok

```
[
 {
   "property_path": "main_skill",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 },
 {
   "property_path": "type",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 },
 {
   "property_path": "description",
   "message": "This value should not be blank."
 }
]
```

How to return custom error like object not plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your data like an array and tell the view to render it as json should generate an output like you wanted to

```
$view = $this->view(
              array(
                'property_path'  => 'main_skill',
                'message' => "error"
                //whatever your object/array structure is
              ),
              500 //error code for the error
            );

$view->setFormat('json');    
return $this->handleView($view);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Symfony's HTTPExceptions as these will be handled by FOSRestBundle.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/4-exception-controller-support.html

```
public function putBitAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $token = $request->get('token');
    if (null === $token) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Provide a secret token');
    }

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Users')->findOneBySecuritytoken($token);
    if (null === $user) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Secret token is not valid');
    }        

    $bit = $manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Bit')->find($id);
    if (null === $token) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Bid not found');
    }

    $view = $this->view($bit, 200);
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

And how is this a `PUT` request? You should rename is to `getBidAction`.

Comment: I have put logic. And I have in prod twig:
    exception_controller:  ArtelProfileBundle:Exception:showException
this action = return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login_route')); And BadRequestHttpException, NotFoundHttpException not return in prod in prod return login_page, but view work in prod very well